Not able to see Data cloud setup in "Create and Publish a Data Kit" trailhead
I am not able to view Data Cloud Setup in Hands on Org to complete Create and Publish a Data Kit trailhead module.
In the module  Create and Publish a Data Kit segment I am not able to view the Data Cloud Setup
Under Tools-->click Data Kits-->Click New.
Does anyone have any solution for this?

This feature is not available in free trail data cloud orgs. We already mentioned the same in the unit content as well.

The module does not have any hands on validation step so this can be skipped.
Reference: https://trailhead.salesforce.com/trailblazer-community/feed/0D54V00007cmP5dSAE
